# Regular Expression in Javascript to test a string of 1s and 0s

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of four bits which represent true/false values. There are only seven valid  options:

```
1010
1110
0000
1101
1001
1000
0101
```

There are three options which could potentially be selected which are not valid and that I want to check for before I proceed with some other code. These are:

```
0110
0100
0010
```

I want to do this with as little code as possible thus having one regex to test all three conditions. My question is if this is a correct regex to accomplish this test. It seems to work, but I am not a regex expert, and have to be sure in this case.

```
 if (!/0(10|01|11)0/.test(precode)) {
     //do some code 
 }
```

Comment: What about 1111?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply test the valids?

```
if((/0110|0100|0010/).test(precode))
```

Seems more readable to me.

Comment: Yeah that is true, I guess I was just trying to be minimalistic.